# UIImageView in storyboard not showing on device and simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` in storyboard. I have placed a `.png` image in `.xcassests` folder. I have correctly assigned the image name to the `UIImageView` which correctly shows in `Xcode` Storyboard. However when I run it on device/simulator, there is no image displayed. When I create the `UIImageView` in code then the image is displayed. My project code is in `Objective-C`

I have tried the following already

1. Clean Xcode project
2. Cleared Derived Data
3. Closed Xcode and restarted device/simulator
4. Deleted all images from `.xcassets` and reassigned

However none of the above has worked for me so far. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: show the code and show the image name

Comment: Disconnect the IBOutlet of `UIImageView` and then run your project. May be you assigned image again from the code.

Comment: did that already. But no luck dear. @the_dahiya_boy

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the image view in in storyboard

Comment: @hamid - check once your image is added properly or not, can you show the code and storyboard scene

Comment: can you attach ur project

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the image is added properly to Target. In fact when I use UIButton and assign this image as background image to UIButton, then it is shown, but unfortunately when I use image view then this problem occurs

Comment: set your button type as custom and check

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it works on uibutton but not on uiimageview

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: I am sorry, the project is confidential. So cannot share the project

Comment: ok do onething create the sample and try once

Comment: Try your logic in the independent demo.

Comment: Can you atleast show the constraints that you have given to the UIImageView ?

Comment: In the independent demo, it works. But not in the actual project

Comment: If it is working in independent demo then figure out issue by yourself :) what exactly happening wrong. Because i think all possibilities you discussed here & in all answers.

Comment: @Mukesh Thank you. This is what I am doing now. Actually I have upgraded project from iOS7 to new iOS10. Do you think there is something that needs to be changed in storyboard i.e. any underlying xml in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should work from what you implemented see. Xcode gets weird sometimes when it comes to referencing resources. I recommend removing the images, clean and build if possible remove the view controller and add again. See if it works.

Comment: I have already done clean and build and even removed assets and reassigned. Also I have tried a new view controller.

Comment: I am sorry, the project is confidential

Comment: no issue hamid i can understand, try cleaning build caches form xcode manually and check the connection

Comment: Thank you. I have cleaned build, even deleted derived data, closed Xcode, restarted device and simulator. However still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no issue with the implementation part. Try adding clips to bounds to imageView

Answer (score 0):

In case other people find this issue and struggle with it. The solution is simple.
Select your XCAssets Container:

[image: Xc Assets]

Then select your target membership in the right hand panel

[image: Select Target]

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the image in Xcode, go to File Inspector, and check the checkbox under "Target Membership". This might help.

Set the alpha of imageView as 1 instead of 0.[image]

Comment: I have checked that, its assigned correctly to the Target.

Comment: Try adding a background color to the imageview and see if it is getting displayed.

Comment: That didnt work. The background color is not displayed. I have checked the uiimageview alpha is 0. I have set it to 1.0 in code and also tried setHidden to false, but didn't work also.

Comment: If the alpha is set to 0 it won't display anything within your view, so can you also check if in runtime, the value of alpha is indeed 1?

Comment: I have checked in runtime after setting alpha to 1.0 in code, its not changed to 1.0. Its still 0

Comment: Then the real problem is with alpha. Can you change the alpha value to 1 in storyboard ?